# Preventing "child div" from overlapping the "parent div"

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div called "maincontent" and within it another one called "leftlist_head". I want to prevent the background of the leftlist head to be contained within the maincontent.

Please see fiddle [here:](http://jsfiddle.net/EBCyt/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id="MainContent">  
<article id="post-1031" class="post-1031 page type-page status-publish hentry">
    <div class="leftlist_head">
            <span><a href="javascript:;" class="sort active showall">Show All</a></span>
            <span><a href="javascript:;" class="sort complete">Completed</a></span>
            <span><a href="javascript:;" class="sort incomplete">Incomplete</a></span>
    </div>
</article>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#MainContent {
float: left;
margin: 20px 20px;
width: 62%;
border: 1px solid;
}

#MainContent article.page {
border: 0 none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0px;
position: relative;
}

.leftlist_head {
background: #DADADA;
border: 1px solid #CFCFCF;
border-top-left-radius: 2px;
border-top-right-radius: 2px;
height: 40px;
margin: 15px 0 -1px 0;
padding: 0 8px 0 8px;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Just give the parent the css overflow:hidden; http://jsfiddle.net/EBCyt/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want .leftlist-head to be able to stay on one line and not go to another line in it's parent div? Try like so:

```
.leftlist_head {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

you have `width: 100%;` for this as well. You may or may not need to adjust this. If the above code does not do exactly as you want, try removing the width line from your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can add position: absolute property to the .leftlist_head 
leftlist head can be like this

```
.leftlist_head {
background: #DADADA;
border: 1px solid #CFCFCF;
border-top-left-radius: 2px;
border-top-right-radius: 2px;
height: 40px;
margin: 15px 0 -1px 0;
padding: 0 8px 0 8px;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EBCyt/8/)

Give your `#MainContent`,  `height:100%;`

also, add

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
}
```

to you css, to give the `maicontent` some base `%age` to calculate width and height for himself, this give the `MainContent` the height   of the required area

Also, in your `.leftlist_head`, you have assigned `width: 100%;` and then you are adding `padding` which will force the `div` to `flow out` of parent as the `width = 100% + padding`...so avoid padding if possible or reduce the width

Answer (score 0):

Check the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EBCyt/9/)**.

Change the css definition as follows-

```
#MainContent {
float: left;
margin: 20px 20px;
width: 62%;
border: 1px solid;
overflow:hidden;
}
```